# Unable to set width in child of Expanded class

Tags: flutter

I created a custom bottom nav bar consisting of a `Row` rendering 3 `Expanded` children representing tabs (blue in the pic).

[image]

Now, I'm trying to render a Container in the middle tab (red in the pic) but I run into a weird problem, I'm able to set the height of this container but when I try to set a custom width for it, it doesn't change anything, the container width stay equal to it's parent's (the Expanded class).

The only way I managed to reduce the container width is by applying a horizontal margin to it but this is not what I want as I need a fixed width.

Any idea of what's going on ?

The nav bar

```
BottomAppBar(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: items,
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
        )
```

The items

```
Expanded(
      child: Container(height: 60.0, width: 100.0, color: Colors.red),
    );
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: `Row(
children: [0, 1, 2].map((i) {
return Expanded(
child: Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Container(
      height: 100,
      width: i == 1 ? 50 : double.infinity,
      color: [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue][i]),
),
);
}).toList(),),`

Comment: @pskink I ended posting an issue on flutter https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27418 and apparently the solution is using the `Align` widget. I still don't know why it is needed in that case tho

Comment: i used `alignment: Alignment.center`, didn't i?